# Android jsonWriter, jsonReader for Gingerbread 2.3

Tags: android, json

Are there other support libraries to allow one to use something like jsonWriter, jsonReader utility classes that are only available in HoneyComb. I noticed they weren't in the official V4 support packages?

It's seems really unprofessional of Google to not provide them as support packages, considering Gingerbread has 50% of the Android market in app store (Google Play).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) a try. I'm using it in all of my projects which have things to do with JSON. This lib also have abilities to parse JSON string to object or object to JSON string.